# Xcode 8 beta 6 AnyObject Swift 3 changes

Tags: xcode, swift3, xcode8-beta6

Xcode beta 6 has changed some of the Swift Language

> Since ‘id’ now imports as ‘Any’ rather than ‘AnyObject’, you may see errors where you were previously performing dynamic lookup on ‘AnyObject’.

I have tried the fix to either cast to AnyObject explicitly before doing the dynamic lookup, or force cast to a specific object type

But am not sure I am doing it correctly - can someone help please here is original working code from Beta 5

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! SpecialCell
        let maindata = values[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
        cell.name.text = maindata["name"] as? String
        cell.id.text = maindata["id"] as? String
        //team_id.text = maindata["team_id"] as? String

        return cell
    }
```

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ln0vx3b9rbywv83/Screen%20Shot%202016-08-18%20at%2014.32.23.png?dl=0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the beta 6 release notes you have to (bridge) cast to `AnyObject`

```
cell.name.text = (maindata["name"] as AnyObject) as? String
```

or force cast

```
cell.name.text = maindata["name"] as! String
```

That's one more reason to prefer custom classes / structs with distinct property types over common dictionaries.

Comment: unfortunately even with either options they both produce the error Type Any has no subscript members still.

Comment: As my data is a JSON feed I was not sure how to use either a custom class or struct as you suggest ?

Comment: How is `values` declared?

Comment: values = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! NSMutableArray

Comment: **Do not** use `NSMutableArray` use at least a Swift `Array` `[[String:AnyObject]]` or `[[String:Any]]`. The declaration as `var` gives you mutability for free.

Comment: Thanks I think I was forced down the NSArray thing by mistake in the first instance.. so I can make values as var values:Any = []  but  let maindata = values[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row] - complains....

Comment: I have to rewrite -  values = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! NSMutableArray  ?  but not sure what

Comment: Please, please don't declare an obvious array simply as `Any`. That's the most unspecified type at all. Help the compiler then the compiler will help you. The JSON collection types are either dictionary `[String:AnyObject]` or array `[[String:AnyObject]]` (in Xcode 8 maybe `Any` for `AnyObject`), so cast the JSON serialization to `[[String:Any(Object)]]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121267/discussion-between-adamprocter-and-vadian).

Comment: Vadian with this update the compiler says, "Method does not override any methods from its superclass". Then when I change the line to `override func awake(withContext context: Any?)` the error goes away. Is it ok to simply change it to `Any?`?

Comment: Yes, it is. All `AnyObject` types in parameters which represent `id` have been changed to `Any`

Comment: Thanks Vadian. Also I tried to find the same release notes [Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/navigation/#section=Resource%20Types&topic=Release%20Notes) but cannot find code changes. Do you have a link?

Comment: I guess the release notes of the beta versions are available only in a developer account.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to make changes to my approach and ditch NSMutableArray (which I am pleased about)

so I declare the empty array as follows

```
var values = [[String:AnyObject]]()
```

and pop the data into it like so now

```
values = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! [[String : AnyObject]];
```

one other minor tweak

```
let maindata = values[(indexPath).row]
```

Job done -thanks @vadian for jumping to chat to help me understand his answer which is technically correct

Comment: Isn't 'values' an array of dictionaries?